# Stop send value to next function

Tags: c++

I have this working code:

```
/* Include files */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

void fnMainMenu(char s);

/******************************************************************************
* Function: fnUpdateSalary
* Description: Update employee salary
******************************************************************************/
void fnUpdateSalary()
{   
    int choice = 0;
    char data = 'a';
    incorrect_input: // goto teleport exit :)
    cout<<"\n\t=======================";
    cout<<"\n\tWelcome\n";
    cout<<"\t=======================\n\n";
    cout<<"1. Update employee salary\n";
    cout<<"2. Main menu\n";
    cout<<"3. Exit system\n";
    cout<<"\n >> ";

    cin>>choice;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    switch(choice){
        case 1 : 
            //fnUpdateSalary();
            break;
        case 2 : 
            fnMainMenu(data);
            break;
        case 3 : 
            exit(1);
            break;
        default :   
        cout<<"Input not recognized. Please enter the correct input.\n";


    }
}

void fnLog()
{   
 char data = 'b';
fnMainMenu(data); // call Main Menu and I want to pass "hello"
}





/******************************************************************************
* Function: fnMainMenu
* Description: Menu for the customer 
******************************************************************************/
void fnMainMenu(char s)
{   
     cout << s;

if (s == 'a')
{ cout << "a = admin";
}
else
{cout << "\n\nb not admin";
}

    //system("cls");
    int chooice = 0;

    cout<<"\n\t=======================";
    cout<<"\n\tWelcome\n";
    cout<<"\t=======================\n\n";
    cout<<"1. Manage employee\n";
    cout<<"2. Search employee\n";
    cout<<"3. Employee report\n";
    cout<<"4. Reset password\n";
    cout<<"5. Exit system\n";
    cout<<"\n >> ";
int numbers = 2;
    cin>>chooice;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    switch(chooice){
        case 1 : 
            fnUpdateSalary();
            break;
        case 4 : 
        //  fnChangePassword();
            break;          
        default : exit(1);

    }
}


/******************************************************************************
* Function: main
* Description: The main calling function
******************************************************************************/
int main()
{   

    fnLog();
    return 0;
}
```

`fnLog()` send `b` to `fnMainMenu()`. When I am at `fnUpdateSalary()` I want to go to `fnMainMenu()` again. My question is, is there anyway from `fnUpdateSalary()` or whatever function available to call `fnMainMenu()` without declaring variable `data` again? I was hoping I could just use `fnMainMenu();` instead of

```
char data = 'r'; fnMainMenu(data);
```

I get this error `error C2660: 'fnMainMenu' : function does not take 0 arguments` if I just called `fnMainMenu();`

I hope my question make sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean like, `fnMainMenu('r')`?

Comment: I want to do this. For example: Inside function `void fnUpdateSalary() { fnMainMenu(); }` I would just call `fnMainMenu();` without sending any data. Appreciate your response. Thank you.

Comment: Well, what would you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter doesn’t seem to serve a real purpose anyway. Passing `b` into the main menu function certainly achieves nothing. If you just want to distinguish between admin and non-admin access, change the type and usage of the argument:

```
void fnMainMenu(bool is_admin) {
    if (is_admin)
        cout << "Admin\n";
    else
        cout << "Not admin\n";
}
```

And call it like this:

```
fnMainMenu(true);
// Or, alternatively:
fnMainMenu(false);
```

That’s it. Incidentally, you don’t need (and shouldn’t!) declare a variable to pass as the argument here. Just pass the value directly, like I’ve done above.

Also, why are your function names prefixed by `fn`? Don’t do this, it’s not good practice. Just use proper names that explain well what the functions do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use your solution. It works. Using `fn..` sounds like a logic name to me. I appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing C++ code and `data` seems to be relatively long-lived with respect to the application logic, it would perhaps make sense to regroup these functions into a class.

`data` could be a data member of this class, and `fnUpdateSalary`, `fnLog`, `fnMainMenu` methods.

```
class Application {
public:
  Application ()
  : data ('b') // default value
  { }

  void fnLog() {
    data = 'b';
    fnMainMenu ();
  }

  void fnMainMenu() {
    if (data == 'a')
      cout << "a = admin";
    else
      cout << "\n\nb not admin";

    // ...
    fnUpdateSalary ();
    // ...
  }

  void fnUpdateSalary() {
    // ...
    fnMainMenu ();
    // ...
  }


private:
  char data;
};

int main () {
  Application app;
  app.fnLog ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I fully understand what you are doing, you need a combination of two things. Firstly, a static variable in fnMainMenu and secondly a default parameter:

```
fnMainMenu(char s = '\0')
{
  static char c;
  if(s != '\0') c = s;
  ...
  ...
}
```

The "static" keyword means that the character will be preserved across function calls. The default parameter means that s will be assigned a null termination character unless you explicitly pass another value.

Comment: You also have a comment in your code above explaining that you wish to pass "Hello". As you are using C++, the easiest way to achieve that would probably be to pass a std::String. Alternatively, pass a pointer to a character array.